# What is the difference between -shared and -bundle gcc flags

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, darwin

I have a tiny C program called abc that uses dlopen internally to dynamically load and run a shared library libabc. libabc declares a function greeting that gets loaded and called dynamically at runtime. When I compile and run with the following two methods, the result works the same. What is the difference between -shared and -bundle flags on the GCC compiler when creating a shared object (.so) C library?

### Method 1

```
cc -c libabc.c -o libabc.o
cc **-shared** -o libabc.so libabc.o
cc -Wall -g abc.c -ldl -o abc
./abc ./libabc.so greeting "Hello World"
```

### Method 2

```
cc -c libabc.c -o libabc.o
cc **-bundle** -o libabc.so libabc.o
cc -Wall -g abc.c -ldl -o abc
./abc ./libabc.so greeting "Hello World"
```

Using Darwin gcc 4.2

Comment: The `-bundle` option is darwin-specific.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use `-bundle`, the generated shared object can't be unloaded again with dlclose() after you dlopen() it; it will stay in memory for the whole lifetime of the process. `-bundle` produces files of type MH_BUNDLE.

Btw, the recommended (but not mandatory) extension for bundles is `.bundle`, not `.so`.